# Stereo 3.5mm jack to RCA or 6.35mm jack on Yamaha MG24?

Tags: mixer, cable

I want to connect an iPod / Computer etc with a stereo 3.5mm jack to a Yamaha MG24.

The MG24 has a stereo channel with both a pair of RCA inputs and a pair of 6.35mm jacks (see below, illustration from the manual shows the MG32 so has different channel numbering). Which pair of inputs should I use?

[image: Yamaha MG24 Back Panel]

Either way I would be using straight-through cables without any additional adapters:

[image: Stereo 3.5mm to 2x 6.35mm cable]

[image: Stereo 3.5mm to 2x RCA cable]

Here is a wiring diagram for the stereo channels from the manual but it is a little beyond me:
[image: Stereo Channel Wiring Diagram]

Comment: I'd just experiment. Try RCA first. If it's too hot, swap to jacks. idk whether that mixer would be expecting -20 over RCA & -10/+4 with a pad on jacks, but that would be a fair guess.

Comment: From your added diagram, looks like the RCA & jacks are simply wired in parallel, so it shouldn't make any difference which you use, though jacks might be more robust. The gain is a full sweep -34 ~ +10, plus a pad; should be enough to cope with most things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either, depending on what cables you have available to you.
For a computer, 3.5mm (AUX) stereo to RCA stereo as shown in photo will work for you, or a 3.5mm Stereo to 2x 6.5mm Mono (left and right).